# AngularJS 1.0.7 change url

Tags: angularjs, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

I have an AngularJS1.0.7 web application. I´m implementing multilanguage urls like domain.com/es or domain.com/en. I.e I have www.domain.com/es/about.

In the other hand, I have a select combobox in navigation bar to change the language. So, when user change language url language part should change.

How should I achieve this?

Note: Please, I do know ui-router. I will evaluate it, but the change in the code is quite big. So, I will like to know an approach with ng-route.

Note 2: I also know my angular version is old. In later AngularJs versions I know there is $route.updateParams({language: newValue}); But, it´s not available in my version.

Comment: You can simply replace language part of the url and set new path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply replace language part of the url (which is always in the beginning) and set new path:

```
// Read current path, e.g. /es/about
var path = $location.path();

// Replace language path
var newLang = 'en';
var newPath = path.replace(/^\/.*?\//, '/' + newLang + '/');

// Set new path, e.g. /en/about
$location.path(newPath);
```

Comment: Everything right, but the detail it´s not working for domain/ and domain/es

Comment: @Rober `$location.path()` retrieves pathname path of the URL, i.e. without domain part. It will always be like `/es/something`.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
$scope.$watch('language', function (newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue !== oldValue) {
            var path = $location.path();
            path = path.replace('/'+oldValue+'/', '/'+newValue+'/');
            console.log(path);
            $location.path(path);
            $route.reload();
        }
    });
```